# how to detect memory leak in new sdk 3.2?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented ipad application foe that i want to check memory leak.I know that there is some extra feature for memory leak.but i dont know how to enable.please advice me if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for memory leak you can run your app with the Leaks tool. To do so, go to Run > Run with Performance Tool > Leaks.

In order to get precise information about leaks, activate "Extended detail" by pressing CMD-E, and click on a leaked block.